# Submit value of output calculation in HTML5

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a simple form in HTML that receives the values for a person's last name and first name. Then I use a PHP file that submits this form into a MySQL database.

I want to make a third variable called 'name' that consists of 'firstname' and 'lastname' together, and I want this 'name' to be submitted to the database.

However, I also have to display 'name' as the user types his last name and first name. For this, I'm using the 'oninput' and 'output' tag combinations. This is a shortened version of my HTML file:

```
<form 
 action="file.php" 
 method="post" 
 oninput="name.value=lastname.value + space.value + firstname.value">

 <input type="text" id="space" value=" ">

 <output id="name" name="name">
 <input type="text" class="text" name="lastname">
 <input type="text" class="text" name="firstname">

 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And this is what I'm doing in the PHP file:

```
$name= $_POST['name'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (name) VALUES ('$name')";
```

I think the problem is that I can't simply submit the value of an output? Because this works fine if I want to submit 'lastname' or 'firstname' which are both inputs.

Please help!

PS: Is there an easier way to include a space on the 'oninput' part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply concatenate them after receiving?

> HTML

```
<form  action="file.php" method="post"> 
<input type="text" class="text" name="lastname">
<input type="text" class="text" name="firstname">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

> PHP

```
$name1  =  $_POST['firstname'];
$name2  =  $_POST['lastname'];

$name   =  $name1 . " " . $name2;

$sql    =  "INSERT INTO table1 (name) VALUES ('$name')";
```

Comment: Because I have no knowledge of PHP whatsoever, clearly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @naranjja that's okay, we have all been there. Please accept my answer if it has helped you :)